# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List Models.User.getevents()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, lista

he retomado una app que deje sin terminar despues de unos 6 meses y me he topado con un fallo que antes no me daba, el fallo es el que pone en el titulo, no lo entiendo muy bien pues lo declaro antes de usarlo. dejo el codigo:

aquí es donde me da el fallo

```
 User users;

public void allOk(View ok) {
    if(!mTitle.getText().toString().equals( "" ) &&  !mCode.getText().toString().equals( "" ) && !mDatePicker.getText().toString().equals( "" )){
        Event event = new Event();
        if(uri==null){
            uri= Uri.parse( "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/o/lamp_minimalism_art_hand_104566_1920x1080.jpg?alt=media&token=19da389c-ef6e-41a0-8acf-877315c8d4f2" );
            // not null not empty
            event = new Event(databaseReference.push().getKey()
                    , mCode.getText().toString()
                    , mTitle.getText().toString()
                    , mDescription.getText().toString()
                    , mDatePicker.getText().toString()
                    , uri.toString()
                    , anio
                    , mes
                    , dia
            );
        }else{
            // not null not empty
            event = new Event(databaseReference.push().getKey()
                    , mCode.getText().toString()
                    , mTitle.getText().toString()
                    , mDescription.getText().toString()
                    , mDatePicker.getText().toString()
                    , uri.toString()
                    , anio
                    , mes
                    , dia
            );

        }

        databaseReference.child(EVENTS_NODE).child(event.getCode()).setValue(event);

        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        nombre=user.getDisplayName();
        email=user.getEmail();
        codigo=mCode.getText().toString();

        String emilio= Objects.requireNonNull( user.getEmail() ).replace( ".","" );
        databaseReference.child( EVENTS_NODE ).child( event.getCode()).child(USERS_NODE).child( emilio).setValue(users);


        Intent intent=new Intent(this, EventActivity.class );

        intent.putExtra("code",mCode.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra( "data",mDatePicker.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra( "uri",uri.toString()); // Si esta vacio da un error en la app
        intent.putExtra( "random",random );

        // AQUI EL FALLO
        users.getevents().add(codigo);

        databaseReference.child( "Users" ).child( user.getUid() ).setValue( users ); //Borra toda la lista, no actualiza y agrega

        floating.setEnabled( true );

        transition = new Fade( Fade.OUT );//Fade.IN
        transition.setDuration( 1000 );// tiempo de la transicion 1000=1seg
        transition.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator() );
        getWindow().setExitTransition( transition );



        startActivity(intent, ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation( this ).toBundle() );
    }else{
        Toast.makeText( this, "Titulo fecha y Codigo son obligatorios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

}
```

y luego la clase User

```
public class User {

private String name;
private String email;
private String avatar;
private List<String> events;
private String vote;


//Constructor
public User() {
    this.events = new ArrayList<>();
}

public User(List<String> events) {
    this.events = events;
}

public User(String name, String email, String avatar) {

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.events = new ArrayList<>();
}
etc
```

Agradecería alguna ayuda

adjunto base de datos donde tendria que ir el dato que se recoge y da el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, podrías por favor colocar mas información?, al parecer es que estas llamando mal algo, o no estas llamando el mismo tipo de dato que implementaste para usar.

Comment: Buen día, puedes verificar si users trae información pudiera ser que ahí sea el problema

Comment: @Luis users siempre es null, supongo que de ahi el problema, lo raro que anteriormente este fallo no me lo daba.
DavidVillegas Introduzco base de datos donde en teoria tendria que ir lo que se recoge en users.

Comment: Al final he dado con la solución, en las reglas de la  base de datos tenia escritura y lectura en false, ahora funciona bien. Gracias por vuestro tiempo